# Need some explanation on HTML, nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

**NOTE: SEE BELOW FOR CLEARER EXPLANATION**

I'm trying to figure out why this is happening.

[jsFiddle 1 - Before](http://jsfiddle.net/TeqUF/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="chicken">
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div>
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div>
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div>
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div>
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div>
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.chicken { width:100%; background:#999; float:left; }

.big-chix { width:48%; margin:0.5%; padding:0.5%; background:#666; float:left; }

.big-chix:nth-child(2n+1) { background-color:#eee; }
.big-chix:nth-child(2n+2) { background-color:#aaa; }
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to put a different background for `.big-chix` class for nth children 1, 3 , 5... and 2, 4, 6...

But when I put in a paragraph (or anything else like a div, etc for that matter), it becomes like this:

[jsFiddle 2 - After](http://jsfiddle.net/TeqUF/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="chicken">
    <p>paragraphy</p>
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div>
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div>
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div>
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div>
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div>
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.chicken { width:100%; background:#999; float:left; }

.big-chix { width:48%; margin:0.5%; padding:0.5%; background:#666; float:left; }

.big-chix:nth-child(2n+1) { background-color:#eee; }
.big-chix:nth-child(2n+2) { background-color:#aaa; }
```

The nth-child placement switches places. Why is this so? Isn't `.big-chix:nth-child()` only suppose to select all the `.big-chix` classes (which is 6 `.big-chix`), then set 1, 3, 5 to a `background-color` of `#eee`, and 2, 4, 6 to `#aaa`?

---

EDIT: From what I gather, `nth-child` will not apply to an element child in the element parent in a code like this:

[jsFiddle - nth-child(1) when `<p>` paragraph is the first element](http://jsfiddle.net/TeqUF/3/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="chicken">
    <p>paragraphy</p> [this is nth-child(1)]
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div> [this is nth-child(2)]
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div> [this is nth-child(3)]
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div> [this is nth-child(4)]
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div> [this is nth-child(5)]
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div> [this is nth-child(6)]
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div> [this is nth-child(7)]
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.chicken { width:100%; background:#999; float:left; }

.big-chix { width:48%; margin:0.5%; padding:0.5%; background:#666; float:left; }

.big-chix:nth-child(1) { background-color:#eee; }
```

**BUT**, it will work in a parent element that has `.big-chix` as the first element.

[jsFiddle - nth-child with `.big-chix` as the first element](http://jsfiddle.net/TeqUF/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="chicken">
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div> [this is nth-child(1)]
    <p>paragraphy</p> [this is nth-child(2)]
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div> [this is nth-child(3)]
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div> [this is nth-child(4)]
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div> [this is nth-child(5)]
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div> [this is nth-child(6)]
    <div class="big-chix">Contento</div> [this is nth-child(7)]
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.chicken { width:100%; background:#999; float:left; }

.big-chix { width:48%; margin:0.5%; padding:0.5%; background:#666; float:left; }

.big-chix:nth-child(1) { background-color:#eee; }
```

Comment: is this a bad question? I'm only trying to learn.

Comment: No it's not, but it's been asked many times. Some people don't like seeing the same question many times over, even if it's not necessarily a duplicate.

Comment: I couldn't find the answer though, maybe I was searching the wrong keywords. that's why I asked.. ah well. at least I'm learning.

Comment: `:nth-child()` is highly misunderstood, but there's really not a lot of keywords to go by. Your question seems fine to me, so don't worry about wayward downvotes.

Comment: I... think I'm getting the hang of nth-child if what I assumed in Quentin's answer was right.

Comment: Yep it's absolutely right. "The nth element in the parent" is the simplest explanation for it.

Comment: There, i edited it for further clarification.

Comment: And added in numbering so people can understand it better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Isn't .big-chix:nth-child() only suppose to select all the .big-chix classes (which is 6 .big-chix), then set 1, 3, 5 to a background-color of #eee, and 2, 4, 6 to #aaa?

No.

`:nth-child()` selects "The nth element in the parent", not "The nth element that also matches the other parts of the selector".

Each selector is applied independently and only elements that match all the components will match the complete selector.

Note, however, that there is [`:nth-of-type()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo) which should do what you want.

Comment: So what you mean is, if I apply `.big-chix:nth-child(2)`, it will select the 2nd element from the `div`, `.chicken`?

Comment: "Note, however, that there is `:nth-of-type()` which should do what you want." But only because those are `div` elements whereas the element that was added is a `p` element. The `.big-chix` class is irrelevant.

Comment: @RenoYeo — No, it will select the 2nd element in the `div` *if* it is *also* a member of the class `.big-chix`.

Comment: @Quentin ...hey can you please update his second fiddle with your solution `:nt-of-type`.

Comment: @Quentin the `div`? which `div`? `.chicken`, or `.big-chix`?

Comment: @Quentin from what I gather, it means it will get the parent of the listed class, then process the children, then apply the style to every specified nth-child inside the parent. Am i right?

Comment: @RenoYeo — *Any* element with child elements that are members of the `big-chix` class, one of which is the second child.

Comment: @Quentin right. I think what you mean is actually the same thing of what I wrote...

Answer (score -2):

use these

```
.big-chix:nth-child(even) { background-color:#eee; }
.big-chix:nth-child(odd) { background-color:#aaa; }
```

works in http://jsfiddle.net/TeqUF/2/